# Mvvm light. Смена view.

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Вообщем суть вопроса такова. Созданы у меня два пользовательских контрола и одно главное окно window. В него я гружу эти контролы. При нажатии на кнопку вход я хочу менять ни пользовательский контролл , а сам Windows. Который грузится при старте. Как его можно сменить динамически? Или это не верный подход?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может как то некорректно был задан вопрос. 
Но проблему решил с помощью messages.

```
Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, (message) =>
        {
            switch (message.Notification)
            {
                case "CloseWindow":
                    Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage("NewCourse"));
                    var appWindow= new appWindowView();
                    appWindow.Show();   
                    this.Close();            
                    break;
            } 
        }
```

Но тут мне кажется уже нарушается принцип MVVM.